Unable to change SDDM on KDE Plasma
I'm unable to set a new SDDM on the KDE Plasma, it does ask for my password but it doesn't change anything.
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.10
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.6.2
Kernel Version: 6.11.0-12-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
